# Loading from jenkins job to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, jenkins

I am able to use the Jenkins API to get information about my build via the url  `http://localhost:1111/job/api/json`

What is inside this jenkins doesn't matter.

When I use json file on my PC I can get values for example in a way:

```
$string = file_get_contents($fileName.'.json');
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo $json_a['something']['somethingdeeper'];
```

I'm looking for something like, but of course instead of file an URL:

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://localhost:1111/job/api/json');
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo $json_a['something']['somethingdeeper'];
```

Any ideas? Didn't find a right solution, thanks.

Comment: What's the problem quering the localhost URL? Be sure you have [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) activated

Comment: u mean I can put URL inside file_get_contents? Is this even possible? :O

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: so actually thing which I did will work for me? :O let me check this!

Comment: Yes, it works. just take a look to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the url of your Jenkins job 
http://localhost:1111/job/projectx

you should add the api/json add the end of the url.

This wil do the trick

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://localhost:1111/job/projectx/api/json');
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($json_a);
//echo $json_a['something']['somethingdeeper'];
```